# how to retrieve the query stats for a cosmosdb through rest api exposed?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I wanted to get the query stats for a container in JSON or any other format supported from azure cosmosdb. Is there a way to get the query stats for a specific query from the azure cosmosdb through the rest api exposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get query stats from response header.

Code:

```
var qry = new SqlQuerySpec { query = "SELECT * FROM root" };
var result = await client.PostWithNoCharSetAsync(new Uri(baseUri, resourceLink), qry);
            //get response header
Console.WriteLine("result:" + result);
            //get documents
Console.WriteLine("result content:" + result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Result:
[image]

You can get code sample here.https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/blob/master/samples/rest-from-.net/Program.cs